# Present active searchBar on segue swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two view controllers.

A view controller with a button, and a view controller with a UITableView and a UISearchBar.

When the user taps on the button in the first view controller, the app should segue to the table view and immediately present an active search bar, ie. I don't want the tableView to present itself, and then have the search bar activate, it needs to be active with the typing indicator already blinking the moment the user sees it.

The effect I am going for is the same as seen in the Yahoo Finance app when you tap on the "Show Quote" search bar at the top of the app.

**Attempted Solution:**

```
class myTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    var searchController: UISearchController!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        configureSearchController()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwind", sender: self)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func configureSearchController() {
        // Initialize and perform a minimum configuration to the search controller.
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        // Place the search bar view to the tableview headerview.
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.isActive = true
        searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

My attempted solution only activates the search bar once the view is visible (the user still sees the search bar without a typing indicator for a moment).

I don't know if there some way around this using prepareForSegue or any other method.

Any help is greatly appreciated!